# what is the good gvim guifont for C/C++ programming

Tags: c++, c, vim

I am trying to find an optimal font for gvim to program in C/C++.

I currently have the following  in ~/.gvimrc and I don't like it:

```
if has("gui_gtk2")
    set guifont=MiscFixed\ 11
else
    set guifont=-misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--10-100-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
endif
set columns=80 lines=50
set guioptions-=T "hide toolbar

"Try to load happy hacking teal colour scheme
"I copy this to ~/.vim/colors/hhteal.vim
silent! colorscheme hhteal
if exists("colors_name") == 0
    "Otherwise modify the defaults appropriately

    "background set to dark in .vimrc
    "So pick appropriate defaults.
    hi Normal     guifg=gray guibg=black
    hi Visual     gui=none guifg=black guibg=yellow

    "The following removes bold from all highlighting
    "as this is usually rendered badly for me. Note this
    "is not done in .vimrc because bold usually makes
    "the colour brighter on terminals and most terminals
    "allow one to keep the new colour while turning off
    "the actual bolding.

    " Steve Hall wrote this function for me on vim@vim.org
    " See :help attr-list for possible attrs to pass
    function! Highlight_remove_attr(attr)
        " save selection registers
        new
        silent! put

        " get current highlight configuration
        redir @x
        silent! highlight
        redir END
```

Comment: Why include your whole .gvimrc when all you care about is the font?

Comment: you welcome to edit what you consider extraneous. I only left coloring stuff.

Comment: Are you asking about the color scheme as well, or just the font? If the latter, the "set guifont" line is more than enough.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `:set guifont=*` to bring up a font chooser dialog. Once you've chosen a font use `:echo &guifont` to see what to put in your .gvimrc. (remember to `\`-escape spaces)

Personally, I like Inconsolata. From my .gvimrc:

```
set guifont=Inconsolata\ 13
```

Comment: +1 @Laurence G. Agh, I don't have Inconsolata. Another one you'd recommend?

Comment: I also like Andale. What OS/distro are you using? On Ubuntu you can `apt-get install ttf-inconsolata`. On other systems you can download it from http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html

Comment: You may also want to do some searches for "programming font". Here's a good list of some: http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts

Comment: By "Andale" I meant "Andale Mono".

Comment: I found the font: http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/Inconsolata.sfd

where do I put this or how to install it? thx

Comment: I still don't know what OS/distro you're using...

Comment: On RedHat you might want to use an RPM, like this one: http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/devel/i386/levien-inconsolata-fonts-1.01-4.fc12.noarch.html

Comment: Alternatively, I believe that dropping fonts in ~/.fonts might magically work on RedHat. (you may need to restart gvim -- I haven't used RedHat for a few years, so I'm a bit fuzzy on how fonts work there)

Comment: @vehomzzz, use Consolas

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible to use [Consolas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas) font there? It is the best monosize font I've ever seen.

Ok, it is possible. Check screenshot below:

[image http://img.flashtux.org/upload/img132432527b55x895f9d81.png](http://img.flashtux.org/upload/img132432527b55x895f9d81.png)

Comment: +1 for Consolas - been using it for about 6 months now and I love it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [monofur](http://www.dafont.com/monofur.font) - it's quite an unusual monospaced font. Other than that, I use Monaco.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good comparison of a few possibilities [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000157.html).

I used to use [ProggyCleanSZ](http://www.proggyfonts.net/download/) (the slashed-zero version), which is a bitmap font that only really looks any good in size 12 (although it's about the same size as a size 9-10 font).  Very easy on the eyes though and easy to differentiate between `0` and `O` as well as `1`, `I` and `l`.  I have since switched to using [Envy Code R](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/05/26/envy-code-r-preview-7-coding-font-released).

Comment: Brokne links, please consider updating this answer or removing it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Courier New, its good..

my .vimrc includes this code snippet to change the font

```
if has("gui_running")  
    if has("gui_gtk2")  
        set guifont=Courier\ New\ 10  
    elseif has("x11")  
        set guifont=-*-courier-medium-r-normal-*-*-180-*-*-m-*-*  
    else  
        set guifont=Courier_New:h10:cDEFAULT  
    endif  
endif
```